# Text processing and analysis in R

Tags: r, text, processing, text-mining, analysis

I am beginning the analysis in RStudio of an interview I have made. The interview is, normally, made of the interviewer's questions and the subject's answers.

```r
text<- "Interviewer: Hello, how are you?
Subject: I am fine, thanks.

Interviewer: What is your name?
Subject: My name is Gerard."
```

I would like to remove all the interviewer's questions to be able to analyze the interview. I do not know how to proceed in R, actually, I do not even know what exactly to Google.

I would appreciate all the help I can get. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is your data in a dataframe or in a vector ?

Answer (score 1):

base R:

```
text<- "Interviewer: Hello, how are you?
Subject: I am fine, thanks.

Interviewer: What is your name?
Subject: My name is Gerard."
```

this gives you

```
text
[1] "Interviewer: Hello, how are you?\nSubject: I am fine, thanks.\n\nInterviewer: What is your name?\nSubject: My name is Gerard."
```

where the \n are  that you split on with `strsplit(`

```
strsplit(text, '\n')[[1]] # strsplit returns a list
[1] "Interviewer: Hello, how are you?" "Subject: I am fine, thanks."     
[3] ""                                 "Interviewer: What is your name?" 
[5] "Subject: My name is Gerard."
text2 <- strsplit(text, '\n\)

text2[c(2,5)]
[1] "Subject: I am fine, thanks." "Subject: My name is Gerard."
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data is a vector `text` as indicated in the question, we can do:

It seems that your data is stored in `text` -> then try this:

With as_tibble wit transform the vector to a tibble (+/- equal to data frame), then we separate the rows by `\n` and finally we filte:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

text <- as_tibble(text) %>% 
  separate_rows(value, sep="\n") %>% 
  filter(!grepl("Interviewer", value) & value!="") %>% 
  pull(value)
text
```

```
[1] "Subject: I am fine, thanks." "Subject: My name is Gerard."
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I have been a bit imprecise, though. I will be importing interviews on txt Word files. Does the text  still count as a vector? Pardon my coding expression illiteracy.

Comment: `dput(my_word_text_example)`, and copy `structure(...)` above into your question as data.

Comment: For future questions please have a look here: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610)>

Answer (score 0):

An approach using `strsplit` and `sub`/`gsub`.

```
text_new <- gsub("\n", "", sub(".*(Subject: )", "\\1", 
              unlist(strsplit(text, "Interviewer: "))))
text_new[nchar(text_new) > 0]
[1] "Subject: I am fine, thanks." "Subject: My name is Gerard."
```

- First split the string using *Interviewer:*.
- Since the first string includes *Subject:* remove the residual string until *Subject:* with `sub`
- Remove existing newlines with `gsub`.
- Finally select non-empty strings.